# Sorting/Grouping on particular column, repeating with all its values thru SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, grouping

I want query should return all rows of table according to sorting of dept not grouping. 
I've tried GROUP_CONCAT() function of mysql, i also want same kind of result but it should return as rows, not only comma separated values..

**Table Data**

```
       
Emp_Id  Emp_Name    Dept
1       aa          111
2       bb          222
3       cc          333
4       dd          222
5       ee          111
6       ff          333
7       gg          222
8       hh          111
9       ii          333
10      jj          222
```

**Expected Output Sort Result**

```
       
Emp_Id  Emp_Name    Dept
1           aa          111
2           bb          222
3           cc          333
5           ee          111
4           dd          222
6           ff          333
8           hh          111
7           gg          222
9           ii          333
10          jj          222
```

Query result should fetch all rows of table, but sorting should be according to dept column, that too without grouping.

Please find attached image for specification -

**Input Data and Expected Sorting Result**

[image]

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: It'd be nice for you to show what you are currently using in your query

Comment: You should include all relevant details in the question.  External links sometimes fail.

Comment: In SQL Server I would solve this with a ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ..) structure.   But I don't know if MySQL supports that.

Comment: @TabAlleman My sql doesnt support `row_number()` you need use variables

Comment: @GordonLinoff He need more rep to include pictures :(

Comment: Thank you all, especially @TabAlleman , googled ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ..)  and found similar suggestion on http://moinne.com/blog/ronald/oracle/ranking-your-results-using-rank-dense_rank-and-row_number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91d37/7)

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (
    SELECT `Emp_Id`, `Emp_Name`, `Dept`,
           CASE `Dept`
              WHEN @curDept THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
              ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curDept := Dept 
           END as RANK
    FROM Table1
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curDept := '') r
    ORDER BY `Dept`, `Emp_Name`
    ) t
ORDER BY RANK, `Dept`
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| Emp_Id | Emp_Name | Dept | RANK |
|--------|----------|------|------|
|      1 |       aa |  111 |    1 |
|      2 |       bb |  222 |    1 |
|      3 |       cc |  333 |    1 |
|--------|----------|------|------|
|      5 |       ee |  111 |    2 |
|      4 |       dd |  222 |    2 |
|      6 |       ff |  333 |    2 |
|--------|----------|------|------|
|      8 |       hh |  111 |    3 |
|      7 |       gg |  222 |    3 |
|      9 |       ii |  333 |    3 |
|--------|----------|------|------|
|     10 |       jj |  222 |    4 |
```